# A Maker's/Goetic's starting general spell in Invisible Sun

Tags: spells, character-creation, invisible-sun

The order description for the Maker and Goetic grants a “general spell that [the character] has enough Sorcery to cast,” but it's not really clear what that means. Does that equate to spell level, or is it more complicated? So, if the PC has 6 points in Sorcery, does that allow them to know up to a 6th level spell?

Comment: The game system is mentioned in the question's title. I don't have enough reputation to create new tags, and none exist for Invisible Sun.

Comment: Ah ok, no worries. I've gone ahead and created the tag for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section seems oddly worded, but is worded very precisely for a reason. First, some groundwork. The Way states (emphasis mine):

> Spell or effect level is a single number that holds a lot of information. **The cost to cast or perform a practice is equal to its level in Sorcery bene.**
>   Level is also the number you add to your venture when you cast or perform the practice to see if it takes effect.

There are a number of secrets that increase the Level of a practice, either by spending more Sorcery (Magnify Spells), or by increasing Level without increasing cost (the [Colour] Thumb secrets), however (to the best of my searching), there are no ways to get a discount to the cost of a spell.

**This has several important implications.** If my visla has the Pale Thumb secret, and a Sorcery of 6, they could spend 6 Sorcery, cast a Level 6 (base) spell, and it would come into existence as a Level 7 spell. However, if we do the check in reverse:

**Does the visla have enough Sorcery to cast a Level 7 general spell?**

The answer is **no**. Despite the specific situation of Pale Sun Spells, a Level 7 general spell will cost 7 Sorcery (as above), so my visla would not pass this check.

In other words, the mechanical check that the statement "general spell that [the character] has enough Sorcery to cast" implies is:

**Does the visla have enough Sorcery to cast [this spell]?** for any given spell.

If the answer is yes, then they can learn that general spell as a part of the char-gen and/or joining the order.